# Extract text count from a list of elements

Tags: python, list, countvectorizer

I have a list containing text elements.

```
text = ['a for=apple','b for=ball', 'd for=dog', 'e for=elephant', 'a for=apple', 'd for=dog', '1.=one', '2.=two']
```

I need to get a count of text that is present before "=". I used CountVectorizer as below with a token pattern but it is not giving the expected results

```
print(text)
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern="^[^=]+")
vectorizer.fit(text)
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

Which gives output as below

```
{'a for': 2, 'b for': 3, 'd for': 4, 'e for': 5, '1.': 0, '2.': 1}
```

But the expected output should be

```
{'a for': 2, 'b for': 1, 'd for': 2, 'e for': 1, '1.': 1, '2.': 1}
```

Also i need to remove the "." from "1." so that my output would be

```
 {'a for': 2, 'b for': 1, 'd for': 2, 'e for': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1}
```

Is there any way i can do that ?

Comment: iterate through the list and replace `"."` with `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> text = ['a for=apple','b for=ball', 'd for=dog', 'e for=elephant', 'a for=apple', 'd for=dog', '1.=one', '2.=two']
>>> Counter(x.split('=')[0].replace('.', '') for x in text)
Counter({'a for': 2, 'd for': 2, 'b for': 1, 'e for': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1})
```

Which firsts splits each string in text by `"="` into a list, and takes the first element from that. Then `replace()` is called to replace any instances of `"."` with `""`. Then finally, it returns a `Counter()` object of the counts.

**Note:** If you want to return a pure dictionary at the end, you can wrap `dict()` to the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
dictionary = {}

def remove_special_characters(value):
    if '.' in value:
        return re.sub(r'\.=\w+','',value)
    return value.split('=')[0]
for value in text:
    new_value = remove_special_characters(value)
    if new_value in dictionary:
        dictionary[new_value] += 1
    else:
        dictionary[new_value] = 1
print(dictionary)
>>>{'a for': 2, 'b for': 1, 'd for': 2, 'e for': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

text = ['a for=apple','b for=ball', 'd for=dog', 'e for=elephant', 'a for=apple', 'd for=dog', '1.=one', '2.=two']

text = [i.split('=')[0] for i in text]      #consider only the first part of the split
text = [i.split('.')[0] for i in text]
frequency = {}
for each in text:
    if each in frequency:
        frequency[each] += 1
    else:
        frequency[each] = 1
print(frequency)                        #if you want to use dict

counts =list(Counter(text).items())     #if you want to use collections module
print(counts)
```

Note that this will work only for what your `text` list says,i.e, contains exactly one `=` , other than that, you'll need to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without CountVectorizer:

```
text = ['a for=apple','b for=ball', 'd for=dog', 'e for=elephant', 'a for=apple', 'd for=dog', '1.=one', '2.=two'] 
left_sides = [pair.split('=')[0].replace('.','') for pair in text]
uniques = set(left_sides)
counts = {i:left_sides.count(i) for i in uniques}
print(counts)
```

which yields:

```
{'d for': 2, 'b for': 1, '1': 1, 'a for': 2, '2': 1, 'e for': 1}
```